# How to add a challenge password attribute during csr generation using python openssl?

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, pyopenssl

I have a python code for Csr and key generation using pyopenssl. I am trying to add an additional attribute, "challenge password" while generating the CSR. Could someone please help on implementing challenge password to the below code?

Additional attribute using openssl look something like this:
Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:asdfasdf

````
import OpenSSL
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate_request, FILETYPE_PEM
def create_csr(common_name, country, state=None, city=None,
               organization=None, organizational_unit=None,
               email_address=None, san_list=None):
        key = OpenSSL.crypto.PKey()
        key.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)

        req = OpenSSL.crypto.X509Req()
        req.get_subject().CN = common_name
        if country:
            req.get_subject().C = country
        if state:
            req.get_subject().ST = state
        if city:
            req.get_subject().L = city
        if organization:
            req.get_subject().O = organization
        if organizational_unit:
            req.get_subject().OU = organizational_unit
        if email_address:
            req.get_subject().emailAddress = email_address
        if san_list:
            req.add_extensions([
                OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension(
                    "subjectAltName".encode("utf-8"), False, (", ").join(san_list).encode("utf-8"))])
        req.set_pubkey(key)
        req.sign(key, 'sha256')
        private_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(
            OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key)
        csr = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate_request(
                   OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, req)
        private_key = private_key.decode()
        csr = csr.decode()
        return private_key, csr
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyopenssl` does not have appear to have support for this.

You could do it using `cryptography` instead, though.

```python
# safe stuff
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID, AttributeOID

# land mines, dragons, and dinosaurs with laser guns
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA256
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import NoEncryption
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import PrivateFormat

# Standard RSA public exponent, should be a "big enough" low hamming weight prime
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#Low_public_exponent_attack
RSA_E = 65537
RSA_BITS = 2048
PEM = Encoding.PEM
PKCS8 = PrivateFormat.PKCS8

def create_csr(common_name, country, state=None, city=None,
               organization=None, organizational_unit=None,
               email_address=None, san_list=None,
               password=None, backend=default_backend):
    key = rsa.generate_private_key(RSA_E, RSA_BITS, backend())
    csrb = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder()
    subject = []
    def add_subject(oid, value):
        if value is not None:
            subject.append(x509.NameAttribute(oid, value))

    add_subject(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, common_name)
    add_subject(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, country)
    add_subject(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, state)
    add_subject(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, city)
    add_subject(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, organization)
    add_subject(NameOID.ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME, organizational_unit)
    add_subject(NameOID.EMAIL_ADDRESS, email_address)
    csrb = csrb.subject_name(x509.Name(subject))

    if san_list is None: san_list = [common_name]
    sans = list(map(x509.DNSName, san_list))
    csrb = csrb.add_extension(x509.SubjectAlternativeName(sans), critical=False)

    # challenge password is included as plaintext in the request
    if password is not None:
        csrb = csrb.add_attribute(
            AttributeOID.CHALLENGE_PASSWORD,
            password.encode('utf-8'),
        )

    req = csrb.sign(key, SHA256())

    pem_key = key.private_bytes(PEM, PKCS8, NoEncryption()).decode()
    pem_req = req.public_bytes(encoding=PEM).decode()
    return pem_key, pem_req
```